# How to change value of NSString object of one iOS application into another iOS application in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, nsstring

I want to know how to change value of one `NSString` object in another iOS application in background ? I have already searched on google but I got answer in which he/she suggested Custom URL Scheme. But I want to change NSString object value of one iOS application into another iOS application in background (which is open by first app using using NSURL).

**My problem scenario** is that there are two application 'A' and 'B', 'A' contains a `NSString`  object called 'string'. Application 'B' opened by application 'A' using Custom URL Scheme, and I performed some operations in application 'B' in which a Web service is called. When web service is called then before coming response of web service if I press home button then application 'B' goes into background but I used some code which handle response in background too. **I just want to change** the value of 'string' object of application 'A' when response comes in application 'B' in background.

Comment: You have to use Applcation B's API to get/set data inside.

Comment: I have to change value of 'string' variable of 'A' into application  'B'

Comment: Shared pasteboards might be another option for you if both apps are published by the same vendor.

Comment: @Jonah I am using pasteboards, I hope this will solve my problem. Let me check whole scenario, then I will reply you soon.'

Comment: @Jonah Its working on simulator and iPod touch(iOS 5.1.1). But not working in iPhone 4 (iOS 7.0.3). And tell me one more thing Is this secure ? Because my application contains some sensitive informations.

Comment: It it unfortunate that this is not working for you on a device however I cannot comment as to why that might be without seeing your implementation. Perhaps you should look at some existing questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360895/named-uipasteboard-between-apps/12360915#12360915 for guidance.
I also don't know what "secure" means to you. What is the threat model? Who are you concerned might access this data and what is the impact if they do?

Comment: @Jonah :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882833/is-ios-uipasteboard-secure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution of this issue, in which I had to send one string from one iOS application to another application, and I did it successfully using `NSPasteboard`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to access another app's data. Apple does not allowed that kind of thing. The URL Scheme will be the only answer.

Comment: Can we launch one iOS application from another iOS application in background ?

Comment: No, that's not possible. There're several jobs which allowed in background such as location service. Launching app is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If u keep a database or if ur application fetch data from a webservice(not local), it might be possible.
If 2 applications are fetching from a same database, depending on what data you want, you can fetch and manipulate data as well