# Is iOS UIPasteboard secure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, uipasteboard

I want to know some questions about `UIPasteboard`.

1. Is `UIPasteboard` is secure? means if we save any sensitive / Confidential information in `UIPasteboard` and want to access that data in only two iOS applications, no other application must have permission to access that `UIPasteboard` data. Is it possible ?
2. What is the size of `UIPasteboard`?
3. Data is being saved using `UIPasteboard`, I want to know what are the different cases when data can be loss ?

Comment: You have asked multiple questions in one posting when these should really be different questions (and the title only refers to the first question).  `1.` According to the `UIPasteboard` class reference you can have private pasteboards that only share data between apps with the same Team ID. The security of this will depend on if a phone has been jailbroken `2.`Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3520903/558933 `3.`The following blog post may be of interest: http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/

Comment: @RoboticCat Thank you for reply. And I will check these links. I have one more issue with UIPasteboard in which when I am using UIPasteboard in iOS 6 then it is working fine, but not working in iOS 7.

Comment: If you've got a specific code problem then you should post that as a separate question with the code, expected outcome and what is actually happening.

Comment: @RoboticCat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904046/uipastboard-is-not-working-in-ios-7